# GLib-GObject-Critical error when running python program on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, glib

I'm working on a project for a friend that involves openCV on a raspberry pi 3, and I'm getting an unusual error after it runs for a few seconds. The error is as follows:

> GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

This occurs 3 times before the program finally crashes. I don't understand what could be causing this as I don't even know what GLib is, and don't reference it in the code as far as i'm aware.

I'm converting the code from a desktop version to be compatible with the raspberry pi, so I don't fully understand everything that's happening.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/wingchangwow/raspberry-potter/blob/master/potter.py

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Debug the crash using `G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings gdb --args ./path/to/program` to get a backtrace.

Comment: I would suggest you to update and upgrade your R.Pi and try again. Have a look to https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md

Comment: @PhilipWithnall I can't seem to get that to run, as I don't believe gdb is compatable with python on raspberry pi. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Carles The pi is up to date already.

Comment: @KeeganHeffernan these kind of errors are usually related to compatibility issues related with libraries, like binary expecting to find newer SO library or library compiled for 64bit being used in 32bit, etc.

Comment: If it’s a Python program, you’ll have to specify the Python interpreter on the `gdb` command line: `G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings gdb --args python3 ./path/to/program.py`.